# JavaFX, JFoenix - Button corners are colored, even with rounded corners

Tags: java, button, colors, background, jfoenix

I have a JFXButton with a white background (instead of the "grey" default one), a transparent border and rounded corners. This is my `style` attribute :

```
-fx-border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
-fx-border-radius: 10; 
-fx-background-color: #ffffff;
```

But this is actually what I get :

[image]

As you can see, the corners are colored and I don't want that. Is this a bug from JFoenix or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Think this has no solution since the StackPane inside JFXButton has no class name to call and apply some css. Try posting an issue in the github page. BTW why to grow the border radius since the Material Design specs say that it must stay in 2dp.

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply a radius for the background property, which will let you have rounded corners without any background colour spill.

```
.jfx-button{
     -fx-border-radius: 15pt;
     -fx-background-radius: 15pt;
}
```

[image: rounded buttons using jFoenix]